# Any character except whitespace over 5 spaces long

Tags: regex, whitespace

In the example below, a dialogue between two people I want to match only the interrogators text. (The text on the left)

```
Hello, how are you?                 I am fine.
What is your name?                  My name is Simon.
What does Simon say?                Put your hands on your head.
```

When I perform a regular expression individually on each line I want to extract

```
Hello, how are you?
What is your name?
What does Simon say?
```

However, I also want to allow for room for error in the questioning text allowing for up to 5 white spaces between words. The number of white space between the questioner and the answerer is always over 5 characters.

I have tried this

```
([^ ]| {0,5})*
```

but that captures the whole line

And this

```
[^( {0,5})]+
```

but I guess you can't use parenthesis in between brackets to evaluate the inner text first and specify that as a single character.

Any ideas are welcome, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(.*[^ ])[ ]{5}.*
```

Answer (score 3):

Try capturing using this regular expression:

```
^(.*?) {5}
```

The `*?` is a non-greedy match, meaning that it will find the shortest match rather than the longest. This should give you what you need.

See it working online: [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/H0TBR2d0JL)

Comment: +1, Should be delimited by 6 spaces in the regex since up to and including 5 spaces is allowed in the text, but otherwise correct.

Answer (score 1):

[This does it](http://regexr.com?2t7tg):

```
^(.*?) {5,}
```

Comment: +1, Should be delimited by 6 spaces in the regex since up to and including 5 spaces is allowed in the text, but otherwise correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use split instead of match?

`str.split("\s{6,}")`